# copy rows based on the number of a variables (R)

Tags: r

So, I have a dataset with 2 columns  X and Y. Y is an integer between 0 and 5. I need to change the level of the detail of the dataset.

I want to copy the rows the number of times Y indicates  As an example

```
X | Y
______
a | 1
b | 0
c | 2
```

Becomes

```
X | 
___
a | 
c | 
c |
```

*a* remains once, *b* disappears and *c* appears now twice. I do not need to keep the Y number, except in the number of rows of X.

My first thought was to do

```
df4 <- df  %>% filter (Y=4) 
df4 <- rbind(df4, df4, df4, df4)   %>% select (-Y)
```

but that all seems ugly, and it is not generalizable to Y =20 as an example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   uncount(Y) %>%
   as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  X    
#  <chr>
#1 a    
#2 c    
#3 c
```

---

or in `base R` with `rep`

```
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Y),'X', drop = FALSE]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(X = c('a', 'b', 'c'), Y = c(1, 0, 2))
```

Comment: uncount was the perfect function for the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

May be this:

```
df <- data.frame( 'x' = c('a', 'b', 'c'), 'y'= c(1, 0, 2))
rep(df$x, df$y)
or 
## For a dataframe:
df[match(rep(df$x, df$y), df$x),'x', drop=FALSE]
```

**Output**:

```
R>rep(df$x, df$y)
[1] "a" "c" "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
data.frame(
  X = with(
    df,
    rep(X, Y)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  X
1 a
2 c
3 c
```